# Choice of the coordinate system in a spherically symmetric solution

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor

For a static spherically symmetric solution, the metric can be written as 
$$ds^2=-A(r)^2 dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{B(r)^2}+C(r)^2d\Omega^2$$
In some cases, we can write $C(r)=R$ and interpret then $C$ (or $R$) as the radius of the coordinate sphere.

But there are problems for which $C(r)$ is not a monotonic function, so I can't inverse it (I don't have a unique solution to C(r)=R), e.g. the Janis–Newman–Winicour solution which describes a solution in the case of the presence of a massless scalar field (it's a naked singularity)

My question, is what is the meaning of $C$ not being a monotonic function, so what does it mean that I can't choose the Schwarzschild coordinates.

P.S.: In a dynamical process (time dependence) like the gravitational collapse, the condition $C'=0$ corresponds to shell-crossing singularity (p.188/189 of *Black Hole Physics: Basic Concepts and New Developments* by Frolov, Novikov) but I don't know the meaning of it when the metric is static.

Comment: I found that in the case where C is not monotonic and actually have a minimum, we have a throat, a minimum of C(r), which then describes a wormhole solution (page 163/164 of _Black Holes, Cosmology and Extra Dimensions_ by Bronnikov, Rubin).

But what is the meaning of the solution when C has a maximum, a wormhole again ?